# Login to web-page using a google sheets script

Tags: javascript, authentication, post, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to log into a web page to retrieve some data

I am attempting to use the following code to log in to a web page. I used google chrome to determine what information was needed for the payload.

```
function login(strUsername, strPassword) {

  var loginPage = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://login.webpageurl.com");
  var sessionDetails = loginPage.getContentText()
  var testsearch = sessionDetails.indexOf('"authState":"');
  var newStringRight =  sessionDetails.substring(testsearch+13, testsearch+6000);
  var authState =  newStringRight.substring(0, newStringRight.indexOf('"'));


  var payload =
   {"authState":authState,
    "username":strUsername,
    "password":strPassword
   };

  //Logger.log(payload); 

  var options =
   {
     "method" : "post",
     "payload" : payload,
     "followRedirects" : true,
      muteHttpExceptions: true
   };

   var login = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://login.churchofjesuschrist.org/api/authenticate/credentials", options);
  //var sessionDetails = login.getAllHeaders()['Set-Cookie'];
  Logger.log(login);  

}
```

I get the following response in my log file

```
{"status":400,"statusText":"authState, username and password are required"}
```

Any ideas on how I could `submit` the form properly?

Thanks

Comment: Try logging into the page with Chrome Developer tools open under the 'Network' tab and examine the request and server response objects (they'll appear after you try to log in). There's no universal method to log into any website - you must know how this process is implemented on the server that you are trying to access.

Comment: There aren't enough details.

Comment: Hello @Robert Goth, could you please provide more information about the code you provided? Are you trying to get the data from the log in form? Because if that's the case, there's no link/rerouting between the form and the POST request you are trying to make. Or what is the relation between the two code snippets you provided? Cheers!

Comment: I changed the information in my question to hopefully allow for sufficient detail. I also used Chrome Developer tools to find the needed payload feilds. This is above my understanding any pointers would be great.

Comment: I would say provide a content type to the request to make sure the content is of type application/json. Also try logging the form data to check if details are being picked up correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code does not work is because `payload` used for the `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` method is a JavaScript object and therefore it will be interpreted as `form data`.

So what you actually need to do is to make the `POST` request with a JSON payload.

Therefore, the thing that needs to be changed is the `options` you provided:

```
var options =
   {
     "method" : "post",
     "payload" : JSON.stringify(payload),
     "followRedirects" : true,
     "muteHttpExceptions": true,
     "contentType": "application/json"
   };
```

Furthermore, I suggest you read more about the `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` method on the [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) documentation.